Adjust image size to wrapped text (embedding google doc in google earth) HTML
I am trying to embed a google doc in the HTML description of a pin on google earth. While the text is having no issues wrapping into the area, the image in the doc isn't shrinking to the size of the wrapped text (see attached picture).
I have used the following HTML:
<!--************GOOGLE DOC************-->
<style>
#frame1 {width:100%; height:540px;box-sizing: border-box;border: 3px solid black;}
</style>

<!-------------Information-------------->
<iframe id="frame1" 
src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/(id of file)/pub?embedded=true"

frameborder="0"

></iframe>

<!--**********END GOOGLE DOC**********-->

Any ideas on getting the image to proportionally shrink down to the width of the wrapped text?
